# CAKeyframeAnimation not work with subclass

Tags: uiview, subclass, cakeyframeanimation

I move a button with an animation, if I use it inside a UIVIewController all work perfectly, if I try to subclassing a UIView with this animation I can't see it, the button appear into the end point but I don't see it moving.
Where is the mistake?

This is my code:

```
- (void) moveButton:(UIButton *)button fromPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint toPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint {

        CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);

        NSMutableArray *timings = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableArray *keytimes = [NSMutableArray array];

        // Start
        [timings addObject:[self getTiming:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
        [keytimes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];

        // Bounce
        [timings addObject:[self getTiming:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
        [keytimes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];

        CAKeyframeAnimation * animation;
        animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        animation.duration = 2;
        animation.path = thePath;
        animation.timingFunctions = timings;
        animation.keyTimes = keytimes;

        [[button layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
        [[button layer] setPosition:CGPointMake(endPoint.x,endPoint.y)];
    }
```

Comment: Your path moves to the start and does nothing else?

Comment: move to the start and go to endPoint, I'm stupid and I miss CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath, NULL, endPoint.x, endPoint.y); but also with this I don't see the animation!

Comment: Move + move? You should be doing move + line

Comment: Also, a path is super overkill for move+line with only two points

Comment: ok, I'm a stupid! the problem is on CGPathMoveToPoint and on keytime, I konw that is a lot for 2 points but is the first time that I use it for learn something new :)